# how can define two dimensional array of vector in c++

Tags: c++11

I want to define two dimensional array in c++ which each elements are a vector with variable size like below

```
a[0][0]={1,2,3}
a[0][1]={6}
a[1][0]={3,5,6,7}
a[1][1]={3}
...
```

how to defile array "a"?

Comment: How would you do this if the elements' type was `int` instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: @Z. Tabatabai while we at that , we can do `std::array<std::array<std::vector <int>,3>,2> a;`

Comment: I want to know,can vectors have variable size?@Angew

Comment: @Z. Tabatabai it's essence of vector.. vector is variable one and re-allocable, std::array is a static one.Please, read documentation ^.^